# What is superView in this case? (Tabbar APP)

Tags: iphone, tabbar, superview

I have a tabbar app with only 1 tab.

Here is my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
OneDayViewController *oneDayView = [[OneDayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneDayView" bundle:nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:oneDayView];

[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES; }
```

In any method in `OneDayViewController`, I have this code:

```
UIView *superView = [self.view superview];
```

Question is: what is `superView` now? UIView? UIViewController or ... I don't know (sorry about that)

P/S: I ask this because I want to remove OneDayView and add another view to tabbar.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Are you getting nil in superView ?

Comment: @Jhaliya: superView is not nil =.=

Answer (score 0):

Your superview will be tabBarController.view...
(Earlier i have told it is window I was wrong...)

post the code that showing/pushing OneDayViewController... so we can get clear idea about the superview...

Comment: self.window is a subclass of UIView

Comment: i think we have this order: `window` --> `tabbar controller view` --> `one day view`.
So i think `superView` must be something of `tabbar controller view` (because i get it from `OneDayView`), but dont know what it is.
Anyway, i just want to remove `OneDayView` out of Tabbar and add another view (App has only 1 tabbar)